# Is it possible to display the label I searched for in the list of search results in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I tried to visualise my question in the below screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I expect that they're not displaying it because it's redundant. You already know what label you searched for; what you want to know is what _other_ labels are on the conversations that match your search. There's no way to do that with Gmail by itself. I don't even think some stylesheet trickery will help because the information probably isn't there.